# Using SQL to get the Comments Associated with an Order

Tags: orders, magento-1, sql, magento-1.4

Anyone know what the query looks like to grab the comments from an order directly out of the database?
Specifically I want to grab the `user_id` of the comments.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no `user_id` for the comments. A comment is not necessarily added by a user/admin. It can be a response from the payment gateway or a simple status change because the order was invoiced or shipped.

Answer (score 1):

That information is saved in sales_flat_order_status_history

```
SELECT * FROM sales_flat_order_status_history WHERE entity_name = 'order'
```

Doesn't seem like the user_id is part of this table, or even referenced with a foreign key to another table; it would be admin_users table. You could create a custom module to add a field to this table, and to override the controller that saves admin order comments to populate your new field.

Comment: I don't have sales_flat_order_status_history in my database.  I'm using mage 1.4.0.1

Comment: Not sure, i am using EE 1.13. May have been added to later versions.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from sales_flat_order_status_history where parent_id = 12345;
```

This is not working for you? It should work in 1.4

Regards